# Using parallel gem when testing ActiveRecords in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, parallel-processing, minitest

I'm using MiniTest and in my test case, I am creating an ActiveRecord like so

```
test 'importing game from confirmed list' do
  Nba::Game.create(stats_id: 1)
  Data::SportData::ProcessUpdate.new(season_id: 2015, league: 'nba').process_boxscores
end
```

Then, I am running the `process_boxscores` method which is

```
def process_boxscores
   #Nba::Game.all = [#<Nba::Game id: 1, stats_id: 1, created_at: "2015-12-07 20:39:26", updated_at: "2015-12-07 20:39:26">]
   loaders = Parallel.map(list, in_threads: 4) {|game| 
     #Nba::Game.all = []
     build_boxscore_loader(game)
   }.compact
end
```

In that method, the parallel gem is being used which speeds up processes, but it somehow doesn't show the activerecords in the database.

I commented out the results of `Nba::Game.all` out of the parallel block and inside the parallel block.

Any ideas as to why inside the parallel block it is not recognizing the activerecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with the [github issue](https://github.com/grosser/parallel/issues/152) I made, hope this helps others